# Why background color won't show over a background image

Tags: html, css

At [this sample page](http://vmpersonal.com/home%20page%20column%20snippets.html), I would like `.snippet-text`'s `background-color: #FFF;` to extend over the photo above it, like this:

[image]

Why does the photo have precedence over the white background?

I have:

```css
.snippet-image {
  z-index: 998;
}
.snippet-text {
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/mhm-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="one-third">
  <div class="snippet">
    <div class="snippet-image">
      <img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/product-personalized-consultation.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-text">
      <h3>Personalized Consultation</h3>
      <p>The Personalised Fitness Consultation is a premium service. The client has the opportunity to have a face-to-face conversation with Victor (VM Personal CEO), in order to develop the best... strategy towards taking your fitness to the next level.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-action">
      <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="one-third">
  <div class="snippet">
    <div class="snippet-image">
      <img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/product-body-weight-program.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-text">
      <h3>Body Weight Program</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-action">
      <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But these are not making a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your z-index code will work if you add `position: relative;` to both elements. z-index only works with non-static positioned elements.

Give `.snippet-text` a z-index by giving it a non-static position.

```css
.snippet-text {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/mhm-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="one-third">
  <div class="snippet">
    <div class="snippet-image">
      <img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/product-personalized-consultation.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-text">
      <h3>Personalized Consultation</h3>
      <p>The Personalised Fitness Consultation is a premium service. The client has the opportunity to have a face-to-face conversation with Victor (VM Personal CEO), in order to develop the best... strategy towards taking your fitness to the next level.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-action">
      <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="one-third">
  <div class="snippet">
    <div class="snippet-image">
      <img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/product-body-weight-program.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-text">
      <h3>Body Weight Program</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-action">
      <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I would use `translateY(-42px)` instead of a negative top margin, and that will also give the element a z-index, so no need to specify anything a z-index or position.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you Michael.

Answer (score 0):

this code gives what you exactly want. including below 'learn more' css

```css
.snippet-text {
  position: relative;
}
.snippet-action {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/mhm-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="one-third">
  <div class="snippet">
    <div class="snippet-image">
      <img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/product-personalized-consultation.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-text">
      <h3>Personalized Consultation</h3>
      <p>The Personalised Fitness Consultation is a premium service. The client has the opportunity to have a face-to-face conversation with Victor (VM Personal CEO), in order to develop the best... strategy towards taking your fitness to the next level.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-action">
      <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="one-third">
  <div class="snippet">
    <div class="snippet-image">
      <img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/product-body-weight-program.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-text">
      <h3>Body Weight Program</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-action">
      <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```